# How to achieve this Switch Case?

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

Basically, I would need 3 `switch case` scripts for navigation through `HTML` pages, like this:

```
1st:<BR>
index.php?1<BR>
index.php?2<BR>
index.php?3...
```

2nd (this one is with subpages):

```
index.php?1&2
```

Therefore, an example, with the 2nd one: I have a few books that I want to put online and index.php is the main catalog, then index.php?1 is the first book in the catalog, and the index.php?1&1 is the first book and the first chapter in it...

```
And the 3rd:<BR>
**index.php?book_id=1** or<BR>
**index.php?book_id=1&chapter_no=1**
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Of course. Just access it using `$_GET['book_id']` or `$_GET['chapter_no']` .

Comment: looked for/tried anything?

Comment: How to add it? O.o

Yes, but nothing that would help.

Comment: Show us, let us be the judge of that. We need to know your path so far.

Comment: This is the basic switch case script I use...

`<?php
$phpself = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
switch($_GET[' '])
{
 case '': include(""); break;
}
?>`

Comment: you need to switch between each individual get variable, e.g. `switch($_GET['book_id']) { case '1': break; case '2'  ... }`

Comment: I know that, but I want it like this **index.php?book_id=1&chapter_no=1**, not like this **index.php?book_id=1**.

Comment: You could use nested switch if you want to use `switch`

Comment: Can you please explain? How? How to nest it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this trick :

```
switch(true) {
    case $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=='1' : 
        include("PAGETOINCLUDE1");
        break;
    case $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=='1&2' :
        include("PAGETOINCLUDE2");
        break;
    case $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=='book_id=1' :
        include("PAGETOINCLUDE3");
        break;
    case $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=='book_id=1&chapter_no=1' :
        include("PAGETOINCLUDE4");
        break;
    default:
        include("DEFAULTPAGE");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like this :

```
<?php

switch ($_GET['book_id']) {
    case 1 :
        switch ($_GET['chapter_no']) {
            case 1 :
                // do something
                break;
            case 2 :
                // do another
                break;
            default :
                // do default one
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 2 :
        switch ($_GET['chapter_no']) {
            case 1 :
                // do something
                break;
            case 2 :
                // do another
                break;
            default :
                // do default one
                break;
        }
        break;
    default :
        // default action
        break;
}

?>
```

Comment: 1. Where here to include the file for a chapter?
2. And where to include the book's main file?